# How to recover unsaved video file on Android?

Tags: file-system, video, file-management

I've got a Samsung S9 phone and today I was taking a lot of photos and videos.

For one video we pushed record for about 30 seconds and then pushed stop. It appeared to have been recorded.

However, later today I check my photos and videos and the video is not there. Everything else is.

Is there a way to try to recover this video file?

Comment: If your storage is not having read-write failures and you are absolutely certain (use a file manager app to look for it instead of gallery) that the file is still not there, than you cannot obtain it anymore because it was never saved to begin with.

Comment: Yeah I looked with a different file manager and it's not there. Is there a temporary directory to look somewhere?